# Use Excel for client of Asp.Net MVC Site

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel

I write internal site on Asp.Net MVC framework. Theare are many different dictionaries. So I must write (or generate if it posible) many identical code. But, I don't want to do this :)

**So, can I connect Microsoft Excel to my site and change data in my dictionaries?**

Why Excel? Excel have many big features:

- good work with copy/paste;
- filter;
- sorting;
- copy data;

and many others.

I try use odata protocol, but it has hard iterface for integration with excel (many modal windows, many parameters). I want more simple, for example sharepoint intergation (change list in excel) or TFS (can create and modify tasks, bugs and others thinks).

Clould you please write what tehnology can help me?

Comment: Are you asking if you can use Excel to modify dictionaries used during the runtime of your application?

Comment: You can use http://epplus.codeplex.com to read excel files easily (even using LINQ).

Comment: Thanks. But, import is not good idea for every day use. In TFS server you can in one-two click watch data in excel (by the button in excel), then you can modify this data and click one button publish. Its done. I want the same.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Excel to dynamically change hard-coded dictionary values in a compiled application at runtime. You can't use *anything* to do that.

However, if your dictionaries pull data from a database, you *could* use Excel to modify the database values (which is essentially what TFS is doing).

To build a custom application in Excel to do this, you'll want to consider using [Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh133430.aspx).

**However**, it sounds like all you really need is to pull your dictionary data from a database. Here are some links on that:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314145

http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/index_files/csharp-Sample-Dictionary-database-connection.htm